# PHP Convert string to int and calculate

Tags: php

I have two values in two variables that are strings

```
$var1 = "A$2800";
$var2 = "A$1500";
```

I want too calculate

`$diff = $var1 - $var2;`

It should be `1300` by calculating the difference of `2800` and `1500`

Comment: Are all your variable with the same structure ?

Comment: "A$" will always preceding the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode()`

```
$var1 = explode("$", $var1); //$var1 is now an array containing: [0]=A, [1]=2800
$var2 = explode("$", $var2); //$var2 is now an array containing: [0]=A, [1]=1500

$diff = $var1[1] - $var2[1]; //$diff contains 1300
```

Comment: Thjank you and i will try

Answer (score 1):

If your prefix in the string are always 2 characters, begin using substr:

```
$val1 = substr("A$3000" , 2 , -2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply add this to number, first you need to remove `A$`. Eg. using substr.

```
$var1 = "A$2800";
$var2 = "A$1500";

$num1 = (int)substr($var1, 2);
$num2 = (int)substr($var2, 2);

$diff = $num1 - $num2;
```

Comment: but the difference returning is 1

Comment: $diff = $num1(is string) - $num2(is also string);

Comment: @MuhammedNiyaz: no, it worked correctly, PHP is able to count with string. You can change type to int using `(int)` but it sn't neccesary in this case. All oprations (`str_replace`, `substr`, `explode`, ...) returns string, when the input is string too. PHP knows that `'2800'-'1500'=1300` as well as `2800-1500=1300`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `A$` and then calculate -

```
$var1 = "A$2800";
$var2 = "A$1500";
$var1 = str_replace("A$", '', $var1); //2800
$var2 = str_replace("A$", '', $var2); //1500

$diff = $var1 - $var2; //1300
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $c)
```

The above should remove all characters and only keep digits.

```
$var1 = preg_replace('/\D/', '', "A$2800");
$var2 = preg_replace('/\D/', '', "A$1500");
$diff = $var1 - $var2;
echo $diff;
```

For variables simply amend the third parameter and insert the variable.  Example:

```
$var1 = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $var1);
```

:)